# Как получить массив дат от сегодня и на 2 недели вперед?

Tags: массивы, ios, дата, swift3

Как получить массив состоящий из дат в форматированном виде от текущей даты и на 2 недели вперед?

Форматирование необходимо следующего вида:

```
var currentDate = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
var convertedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate as Date)

dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMd")
convertedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())

print(convertedDate) // 18 июля
```

Т.е. необходимо получить массив со значениями: ["18 июля", "19 июля", "20 июля", "21 июля", "22 июля" ...]

Comment: 2 недели вперед - это имеется в виду ровно 14 дней?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Возвращает день через n дней в будущем
func dayInFuture(afterDays: Int) -> Date {

    let today = Date()

    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

    let today0h = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: today)!

    let nextDay = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: +afterDays, to: today0h)

    return nextDay!
}


//Пример завтра
let tomorrow = dayInFuture(afterDays: 1)

//Дни на 14 дней вперед
for dayIndex in 0..<14 {
    let day = dayInFuture(afterDays: dayIndex)
}
```

Используя ваш dateFormatter, получаете форматированные на русском дни.