# Массив вывода дат на 2 недели вперед JS

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Нужно получить массив на вывода дат на 2 недели вперед на чистом JS. Сам в JS плох, нахшел похожий вопрос с ответом но там ответ дан(вроде как) на Jquery([Как получить массив дат от сегодня и на 2 недели вперед?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693486/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4))

Comment: Там теги стоят `ios` и `swift3` где Вы там увидели jQuery?

Comment: [Get all dates in a range of 2 weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842260/get-all-dates-in-a-range-of-2-weeks)

Comment: в цикл запихни и пуш в массив

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/how-to-add-days-to-date

Comment: @Ruslan Gorbunov  уже вчера так сделал(но все равно спасибо). Код выложил в ответе, но мне еще нужно довести до нужного для проекта состояния

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const options = { month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
const date = new Date();
let dates = [];

Date.prototype.addDays = function (days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
};

for (let i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
  dates.push(date.addDays(i));
}

dates.forEach((date) => {
  console.log(date.toLocaleString('ru-RU', options));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал массив с пушем данных. В идеале - мне надо довести код до перевода на русский и пуш должен быть только числа(даты) и месяца

```
JS
        let test = new Date()
        let testNow = test.getTime()
        let f = 24
        let data = []
        data.push(test)
        for (let i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            console.log(f)
            let curData = new Date(testNow + f * 3600 * 1000)
            f = f + 24
            data.push(curData);
        }
        console.log(data)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString
исходя от твоего кода:\n



`const options = { month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

data.forEach(date => {console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', options))})
`

Comment: @Ruslan Gorbunov большое спасибо! Пожалуйста, добавьте ответ из компиляции моего и вашего кодов, чтобы я зачёл вам ответ